# Is there a way to store a variable before it gets changed?

Tags: r, simulation

I'm fairly new to R and my first big project was to simulate the playoffs of a local Quiz Bowl tournament. I've got the code so that it can run as many simulations as I want and print out the champion each time. The issue is, I can't figure out a way to store the past champions anywhere because I'm using the repeat function so each time R goes through my simulation, a new champion is set under the variable Champion. I'll put a little of the code in so hopefully that will help.

```
Count <- 0
repeat {
Champion <-ifelse(Team37 > Team38 & Team37 > Team39,
                  Game13_T1,
                  ifelse(Team38 > Team39,
                         Game13_T2,
                         Game13_T3))
print(Champion)
Count = Count + 1
if (Count == 10000) {
    break
}
}
```

So, I need some way to store all my champions because I want to keep track of and create championship winning probability among other things. There's a whole lot of other mumbo jumbo before repeat and between repeat and the next line of code that I have there but I think that should give y'all the gist. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I'm wondering whether the `repeat` is necessary at all. We can't tell from your non-reproducible code.

Comment: It is more likely than not completely unnecessary, but I was having a very difficult time with some other methods. I'd be happy to share with you separately if you have time or want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming `Champion` is going to be name of the some team so it is going to be of type character. You can initialize a vector at the beginning to store each `Champion`.

```
Count <- 0
all_champion <- character(10000)
#If it's a number use numeric
#all_champion <- numeric(10000)
repeat {
  Champion <- ifelse(Team37 > Team38 & Team37 > Team39, Game13_T1,
               ifelse(Team38 > Team39, Game13_T2, Game13_T3))
  Count = Count + 1
  all_champion[Count] <- Champion
 if (Count == 10000) {
     break
  }
}
```

Comment: @benjanin76 Please consider checking the green checkmark to mark this as the solution if it answered your question